# Two commands when run seperately works but when on a Bash file it does not work

Tags: bash, shell-script, kubuntu

I am using KUbuntu 18.04.1

I am trying to extract text from screenshot using spectacle (Screenshot app of KUbuntu) & gocr (OCR tool)

If I give the commands one after another in Konsole (Terminal of KUbuntu)

**First:**

```
spectacle -r -b -n -o /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg
```

**Second:**

```
gocr -i /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg | xsel -b
```

**It Works.**

if I create a bash file *screen_ts.sh* and put the code

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dependencies: gocr xsel

# Take Screenshot and Save it to a File
spectacle -r -b -n -o /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg

# Extract text from the saved file
gocr -i /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg | xsel -b

exit
```

Open Konsole and type *./screen_ts.sh* , **it works**

But, if I Make the file executable and double click, **it take screenshot but does not save the text in clipboard.**

Again if I create a custom shortcut using

Custom Shortcut > Trigger `Alt + Q` & Action `/home/UserName/Documents/Translate/screen_ts.sh`

[image: KUbuntu Custom Shortcut]

**it take screenshot but does not save the text in clipboard.** Same behavior as double click.

What is going on here.

Comment: Is there in `~/.xsession-errors` any error message?

Comment: Please do not cross-post over several Stackexchange forums. Make a decision where to keep your question up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080828/command-showing-different-behaviour-when-running-from-terminal-and-when-using-as